# How to go to the last files in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I open

File1.cs
then
File2.cs
Then 
File3.cs

Now I want to go back two editor views, is that possible?
e.g. press a button that takes me back to File2.cs 
press again
then it takes me back to File1.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go back
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go forward

Or you can use your side mousebuttons the same as in a browser (if you have any, highly recommended):

[image: mouse]

Finally you have the UI:

[image: UI]

Comment: In settings hot keys it is called `View.NavigateBackward` and `View.NavigateForward`

Comment: Aren't those side buttons (never used them) for back and forward? If so, doesn't that map to something like `Alt+LeftArrow` and `Alt+RightArrow`?

Comment: Not sure how they working internal, but they worked for me without extract configuration in Visual Studio for every mouse I had so far @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting! I might need to start using a mouse with side buttons then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (CTRL + Minus)

Reference: [VS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio)